# When deploying a Windows CE 6 application I get the error: file or assembly system system.data.sqlserverce not found

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, c#-3.0, windows-ce

I am deploying a legacy C# mobile application onto a Windows CE 6 device.

The application compiles within Visual Studio 2008 and deploys onto the device, but an error appears when running my application on the device:

> File or assembly name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, version = 3.0.3600.0, culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3B3235DF1C802AD3' or one of it's dependencies, was not found'.

This application (as you've probably guessed) uses SQL Server Compact, I've tried various  methods to get the application to run (reinstalled SQL Server compact on the device etc) but no joy.

I've also tried altering the **app.config** file to map remap this missing dependency:

```
<dependentassembly>
    <assemblyidentity name="System.Data.SqlServerCe" culture="neutral" publickeytoken="3be235df1c8d2ad3" />
    <bindingredirect  newVersion="3.5.0.0" oldVersion="3.0.3600.0" />
 </dependentassembly>
```

But I am getting still the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried deploying SQLCE 3.0 to the device? SQLCE does not always gracefully handle cross-version loading, even within the save minor rev (3.5 and 3.5SP1 for example won't mix).

Comment: Yes, installed SQLCE 3.0 but still getting the same error...

Comment: Well, even stranger, I installed SQLCE 3.5 and the original error disappeared BUT (and there's always a but!) the application runs but exits immediately back to the desktop after a couple of seconds with no error message displayed?!

Comment: For 3.5 yes, that's a typeload problem, and not unusual.

Comment: So where do I begin with this?! Visual Studio doesn't even return an error!

Comment: Recompile the code targeting SQLCE 3.5, then deploy the exact binary you built against.